# Difference between myObservableArray.length and myObservableArray().length

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have started learning knockoutjs from their tutorial site, specifically the bit on [observable arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html). I'm practising some of the examples.

I want to ask for a very simple clarification, about this code:

```
var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray();  
// Initially an empty array 
myObservableArray.push('Some value');
alert('The length of the array is ' + myObservableArray().length);
```

In the example above, why is `myObservableArray().length` used, instead of `myObservableArray.length`, since both of them give the same output?

In any conventional language, if I want to refer an object I would be using `myObservableArray.length`, so is there any technical reason behind this?

Comment: also from the doc: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables and http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#reading-information-from-an-observablearray

Comment: You can't extend native arrays, so knockout created a wrapper to add functionality. Calling `myObservableArray` returns the actual underlying  array.

Comment: It is just a matter of opinion, but observableArrays are more confusing than helpfull at first. observableArray in easy words is just a modification of observable, that provides array methods and through these methods tracks changes made to array.

Comment: And to finish that last comment, for me it was also pretty confusing

As to your last question - observbleArray as @Jeroin tried to point out is many things. It could be considered a Function and an Object - but that is details. Important thing is  - it is observable, so
`myArray()` - means reading
`myArray([1, 2, 3])` - means writing
`myArray.peek()` - means sneaky reading

And also this observable has additional array methods, which do what docs say they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that `myObservableArray.length` and `myObservableArray().length` give the same output is wrong:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ myObservableArray: ko.observableArray(["A", "B", "C", "D"]) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>myObservableArray.length = <span data-bind="text: myObservableArray.length"></span></p>
<p>myObservableArray().length = <span data-bind="text: myObservableArray().length"></span></p>
```

This is because `myObservableArray` will contain the return value of calling the function `ko.observableArray`, which is *not* an array, but an **observable**.

An **observable *is a function*** with various properties, and note:

- If you call `.length`, you call [the `length` property that all Functions have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length);
- If you invoke the observable as a function, you get the underlying value, which in your case is an array. If you call `.length` on the result, you call [the `length` property that Arrays have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

Bottom line: the two `length` properties are very different things. Almost always will you be interested in the length of your underlying array, which is why you should invoke your observable as a function first to "get" the value.

---

Here's another way to look at this, specifically in the context of view models. Assume this view model:

```
var MainViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.myObservableArray = ko.observableArray(["A", "B", "C"]);
}
```

Inside your view model you could consider "`myObservableArray`" as a property, to be used in three different ways:

- Use "`self.myObservableArray`" as a pointer/reference to the property itself;
- Use "`self.myObservableArray()`" as a "getter" for the property (to "get" the value: an array);
- Use "`self.myObservableArray(["new item"])`" as a "setter" for the property (to "set" a whole new value -new array- to the property).